# Catching exceptions with servicestack

Tags: servicestack

We have been using ServiceStack for REST based services for a while now and so far it has been amazing.

All of our services have been written as:

```cs
public class MyRestService : RestService<RestServiceDto>
{
   public override object OnGet(RestServiceDto request)
   {
   }
}
```

For each DTO we have Response equivalent object:

```cs
public class RestServiceDto 
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus {get;set;}
}
```

which handles all the exceptions should they get thrown.

What I noticed is if an exception is thrown in the `OnGet()` or `OnPost()` methods, then the http status description contains the name of the exception class where as if I threw a:

```cs
new HttpError(HttpStatus.NotFound, "Some Message");
```

then the http status description contains the text "Some Message".

Since some of the rest services are throwing exceptions and others are throwing `new HttpError()`, I was wondering if there was a way without changing all my REST services to catch any exceptions and throw a `new HttpError()?`

So for example, if the `OnGet()` method throws an exception, then catch it and throw a `new HttpError()`?

Answer (score 9):

### Using Old API - inherit a custom base class

As you're using the old API to handle exceptions generically you should provide a Custom Base class and override the HandleException method, e.g:

```
public class MyRestServiceBase<TRequest> : RestService<TRequest>
{
   public override object HandleException(TRequest request, Exception ex)
   {
       ...
       return new HttpError(..);
   }
}
```

Then to take advantage of the custom Error handling have all your services inherit your class instead, e.g:

```
public class MyRestService : MyRestServiceBase<RestServiceDto>
{
   public override object OnGet(RestServiceDto request)
   {    
   }
}
```

### Using New API - use a ServiceRunner

Otherwise if you're using [ServiceStack's improved New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) then you don't need to have all services inherit a base class, instead you can just tell ServiceStack to use a custom runner in your AppHost by overriding CreateServiceRunner:

```
public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(
    ActionContext actionContext)
{           
    return new MyServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext); 
}
```

Where MyServiceRunner is just a just custom class implementing the custom hooks you're interested in, e.g:

```
public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T> {
    public override object HandleException(IRequestContext requestContext, 
        TRequest request, Exception ex) {
      // Called whenever an exception is thrown in your Services Action
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, how do I return the Response objects? Currently if I throw an error, then the Response object (serialised) is not returned, there is no with the response object.

Comment: I did the following :  protected override object HandleException(TRequest request, Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.error(ex.message);
            return base.HandleException(request, ex);
        }