# Is it possible to extend ResponseStatus class in ServiceStack to include additional properties?

Tags: response, servicestack

I would like to include several additional properties that extend the basic functionality, for example `public bool Success { get; set; }` or override `ErrorCode` to return an `int` instead. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you can't extend the built-in types, but you can [override the default error handling to use your own error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143502/catching-exceptions-with-servicestack/13151256#13151256).

But as an int is just a stricter string, I would personally leave it as-is and just use a helper extension method, e.g:

```
public static class ResponseStatusExtensions {
    public int? ErrorNumber(this ResponseStatus status) {
        int errNum;
        return int.TryParse(status.ErrorCode, out errNum) ? errNum : (int?)null;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
if (response.ResponseStatus.ErrorNumber() == 100) { ... }
```