# ServiceStack IService<> Error Handing

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack, nlog

We have successfully implemented the ServiceStack IService<> interface and have it communicating with an iPhone but we are unsure of the best way to implement our exception handling and logging.

```
public class AddCarService : IService<AddCar> 
{

    public UnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    public object Execute(AddCar request)
    {
        try
        {
            PersonBo person;
            if (UnitOfWork.PersonService.ValidateSession(request.SessionGuid, out person))
            {
                var car = new CarBo
                {
                    PersonId = person.PersonId,
                    Name = request.Car.Name,
                    RegistrationNumber = request.Car.RegistrationNumber,
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsDeleted = false
                };
                UnitOfWork.CarService.Add(car);
                var cars = UnitOfWork.CarService.GetCarByPersonId(person.PersonId);
                var mobileCars = cars.Select(carBo => new Car { CarId = carBo.CarId, Name = carBo.Name, RegistrationNumber = carBo.RegistrationNumber }).ToList();
                return new GetCarResponse { Cars = mobileCars, Status = ResponseStatus.Ok };
            }
            return new GetCarResponse { Cars = null, Status = ResponseStatus.Unauthorised };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UnitOfWork.Logging.Error("AddCarService", ex);
            return new GetCarResponse { Cars = null, Status = ResponseStatus.Exception };
        }
    }
}
```

Adding a try/catch has quite a performance penalty so we wondered if there was a function build into the ServiceStack framework to support what we are trying to achieve and still return a well formed response to the iPhone.

Comment: Also see this previous answer on how to generically [catch and handle exceptions in ServiceStack][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143502/catching-exceptions-with-servicestack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inherit from `ServiceBase<T>` instead of implementing `IService<T>` you get this for free (returning a well formed response), but if you take a look at the [`ServiceBase<T>` class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/ServiceBase.cs), you will see that this is done by wrapping the code in a try-catch block.

I don't think you will get much more than this from ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) you can generically handle exceptions by implementing your own ServiceRunner. With the old API you need to override `HandleException()` in a custom base class that inherits from `ServiceBase<T>` or `RestServiceBase<T>`.

See this [previous answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143502/catching-exceptions-with-servicestack).